# Zlib giving error unexpected end of file when using createGunzip function node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, zlib

I am making read streaming by a gunzip file but zlib.createGunzip() giving error (unexpected end of file). I have tried it in all way but not succeeded, below is my code, don't understand how it will be resolve. If there is another way to read(remotely) a gunzip(.gzip) file without saving it locally, please suggest me. I am totally frustrated.
My code:

```
var bytesRead = 500;
var data = []; 
fs.createReadStream('data.csv.gz', {start: 0, end: bytesRead, chunkSize: bytesRead + 1})
.pipe(zlib.createGunzip())                                       
.on('data', async function (row) { console.log(row);
     data.push(row); 
})
.on('end', async function () {
    console.log("Finish");
}).on('zlib error', async function(err) {
    console.log("ZLIB ERROR", err);
})
```

Comment: Why are you reading only a part of the gzip file? This is probably the reason for your error - the compressed data is incomplete.

Comment: I pushing all data inside data array, can get it on end, I have didn't idea to do it in other way, if you have some idea please guide me.

Comment: The question is, why the { start: 0, end: bytesRead } options? What are you trying to accomplish using this? It causes the read stream to only provide 500 bytes instead of the entire file.

Comment: I have did it to read only 500 bytes only for testing purpose, it's a 5+gb file, once testing will be done then I will read whole file. 

I have also tested without it but same issue going on.